# Highcharts fixed label length, prevent chart from being resized

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scale, fixed, label

Hi i wonder if it's possible to disable the automatic scaling of a highchart.

Or is ist possible to set a fixed position and or width and height to the labels ?

Here is an example, this is how i'd like to have my chart look like.
http://jsfiddle.net/ynXgw/6/

But if the labels have a different length highchart shrinks the graph.
http://jsfiddle.net/ynXgw/7/

Has anybody an idea how i could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is to use a different series to display the labels.  In this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynXgw/10/) I use a second scatter series to display the labels.  To position the labels just set the y value.  I set the color of the points to the same color as the background to hide them.  Then I use the dataLabels formatter to display the labels how you want them.